# actualizar node js a versión 14 con npm para utilizar npx create-react-app

Tags: nodejs, npm, terminal

Estoy tratando de crear un app de react utilizando el comando (npx create-react-app) y me dice que debo actualizar node js, pero las version 16 de node no se adapta a mi windows 7.

quiera saber si con npm existe un comando para actualizarlo a la version que yo quiero que es la 14

Comment: Te recomendaría nvm, pero no es compatible con windows. Suelo utilizarlo en WSL (windows subsystem for linux). La opción es una descarga manual: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.18.2/

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue diciéndome que debo actualizar a Windows 8.1 como mínimo.

Comment: Puedes intentar instalar una máquina virtual y trabajar desde ahí.